# Bootstrap modal won't work with the example code

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I used the example code of bootstrap and I used 2 css files and 1 js file.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Small modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Small modal</button>

    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong I just want it to show the modal that I want.

Comment: did you load `jquery` and `bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: How can I make sure it did load? Sorry I'm kinda new to this.
EDIT: one error in the console "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery"

Comment: See my answer below @Goldenowner

Comment: add <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: Glad to see the issue is fixed.  Next time you get an error/issue use F12 in your browser and you'll get a development tool up.  All good browsers have it.... even IE has one :O Chrome and FireFox have the better ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

     <!-- Small modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Small modal</button>

    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                Hello World
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You missed to load `jquery` that's why the modal wasn't working.

Comment: And this jquery file is just a general one that you always need ?